# How to know if a function with three variables is onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is $f:{Z}\times{Z}\times{Z}\rightarrow{Z}$ defined by $f(k, m, n) = 21k + 351m+ 267n$ surjective? Is there a general way to solve these types of tasks?

A similar task said that $f:{Z}\times{Z}\rightarrow{Z}$ defined by $f(m,n)=89n+246m$ is surjective. I manage to get these terms to equal 1, but how do I know there are no exceptions? How can I be 100% sure something is surjective or not?

Usually when I do these tasks I try to make the other variable "null out" the other so I only end up with for example n, but here I don't see how to do that. Does the answer relate to 89 and 246 being relatively prime but $gcd(21,351)=3$? Or to how 21, 351 and 267 are odd while 89 is odd and 246 is even? No idea where to even begin...

Comment: How did you manage to get these terms to equal 1?

Comment: Without giving too much away, the case where we set the function equal to 1 is very important. Can you prove that it forms a necessary and sufficient condition for the function to be surjective?

Comment: Do $21,351,267$ have a nontrivial common divisor?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so fast! <3 (-17)(246)+47(89)=1, since they are relatively prime I used the Euclidian algorithm backwards to find it as a linear combination

Comment: Thank you for replying! I found that 21, 351, 267 all have 3 as a divisor, should I try to make a linear combination?

Comment: If the three coefficients have a common divisor of $3,$ what is true of *any* linear combination of them? (in the integers, that is)

Comment: I do not know how to prove/write it formally and explain the conditions, but does the answer relate to the fact that if you can make it into 1, then you can just multiply that with any number and get any number?

Comment: That is what I was getting at before, yes. However I probably should've noted that this is more relevant to the discussion of the general case than your particular problem.

Comment: Sorry Stephen! Did not see your latest comment. I am a bit unsure but if their common divisor is 3, does that then mean that any linear combination is something multiplied by 3?

Comment: Thank you so so much Stephen, I think it all makes sense now :D You are great, have an amazing day :)

Comment: I guess we can never have 1, thus we lose out on all numbers that are not multiplied by 3 :D You make it seems so easy, thank you :D

Comment: Thanks, you too. I am also writing up a proof for the general case for you to read at your convenience, I think you may find it instructive

Comment: Thank you, that would be lovely! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's consider the case for functions $f: \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z,$ but note that the argumentation extends very naturally to all functions $\mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z$ if we write the function in terms of a sum. I've avoided this in order to simplify the notation.

We will begin by considering the following lemma:

> **Lemma 1:** For any function $f: \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$ where $f(k, n) = ak + bn$ for integers $a, b,$ $f$ is surjective if and only if $ak + bn = 1$ is solvable for $k$ and $n.$ 
>  
> **Proof:** If $ak + bn = 1$ for some integers $k$ and $n,$ then for any integer $d$ we must have that $d(ak + bn) = d,$ and so $a(dk) + b(dn) = f(dk, dn) = d,$ so for any integer $d$ we can construct an input which $f$ maps to $d,$ meaning $f$ is surjective. 
>  
> Otherwise, if the equation is not solvable, then because $1$ is an integer and there exist no integers $k, n$ such that $f(k, n) = 1,$ $f$ cannot be surjective.  $\ \blacksquare$

This allows us to narrow our view from the general case of $ak + bn = d$ to the specific case where $d = 1.$ Now, consider what happens when $\gcd(a, b) \neq 1$:

> **Lemma 2:** If $\gcd(a, b) \neq 1,$ then $ak + bn = 1$ has no solutions where $k, n \in \mathbb Z.$ 
>  
> **Proof:** Let $\gcd(a, b) = g > 1.$ By definition, $g | a$ and $g | b,$ so $a$ and $b$ are equivalent to $0 \pmod{g}.$ Also, because $g > 1$ it clearly must be true that $1$ is not equivalent to $0 \pmod{g}.$ However, taking both sides of our equation mod $g$ yields $(0)k + (0)n = 0 \equiv 1 \pmod{g},$ and we have a contradiction. $\ \blacksquare$

So, we have that if $\gcd(a, b) \neq 1,$ then there are no solutions and the function is not surjective. This argument is equivalent to the one we went over, which is that the outputs of our function must always be multiples of the greatest common divisor of the coefficients.

This alone is enough for the particular problem here, but we can make a stronger statement if we consider what happens when $\gcd(a, b) = 1.$ Here we can apply Bezout's identity to show that there are integers $k, n$ such that $ak + bn = 1,$ and in practice this would be much more efficient, but I thought of a different argument which I found appealing so I wanted to show it. However, if you'd like you can replace this part with a reference to Bezout's identity.

Note that the problem of solving $ak + bn = 1$ is equivalent to finding $k$ such that $ak \equiv 1 \pmod{b}.$ With this rephrasing of the question, we can consider the following argument:

> **Lemma 3:** If $\gcd(a, b) = 1,$ then $a$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $b.$ 
>  
> **Proof:** Suppose that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $a$ did not have a multiplicative inverse mod $b.$ Note that if $b = 1$ then all integers are equivalent to $0$ mod $b,$ so trivially $a \equiv 0 \equiv 1$ and $1$ is a multiplicative inverse of $a$ mod $b,$ so we must have $b > 1.$ Now consider multiplying the integers from $0$ to $b - 1$ (inclusive) by $a$ and examining their residues mod $b.$ Because $a$ has no multiplicative inverse, $1$ is not among the residues of the products. So, we have $b$ inputs and $b-1$ outputs, so by the pigeonhole principle there must be two distinct integers $x$ and $y$ where $0 \leq x,y < b.$ such that $ax \equiv ay \pmod{b}.$ 
> Without loss of generality, let's assume $x > y.$ We now have $a(x - y) \equiv 0 \pmod{b}.$ Rewriting with $c = x-y,$ this means that $b|ac$ for integer $c$ where $0 < c < b.$ Now consider that $b$ must either be $1$ or be divisible by some prime divisor $p.$ Because $b > 1$ as discussed before, we have that there is some prime $p$ and integer $b'$ such that $b = pb'.$ Because $p | b$ and $b | ac,$ $p | ac$ and by Euclid's lemma either $p | a$ or $p | c.$ 
> Because $\gcd(a,b) = 1,$ we must have that $p | c,$ so let $c = pc'$ for $0 < c' < b'.$ Now we have $pb'|apc',$ so $b'|ac'.$ Now by the same logic we must have $q | c'$ for any prime $q$ dividing $b',$ and so forth until we reach $1 | ac^*,$ where $c^* = \frac{c}{b}.$ From this it should be clear that $b | c,$ however this is not possible as we have that $c < b,$ and we have our final contradiction. $\ \blacksquare$

So from the last two lemmas we have that $ak + bn = 1$ is solvable if and only if $\gcd(a, b) = 1,$ and combined with our first lemma we can conclude:

> **Corollary:** the function $f : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z,$ $f(k, n) = ak + bn$ is surjective if and only if $\gcd(a, b) = 1.$

(and again, in general this extends to higher dimensional functions such that the $\gcd$ of *all* of the coefficients must be $1.$)